# Backup Exec - Database page file

Tags: exchange-2007, backupexec

I'm currently running Windows SBS 2008 on a server with a single LTO2 Tape drive. There is SQL server 2008 and Exchange 2007 running on this server. I use Backup Exec 2.5 x64bit to backup on a daily basis

Until Recently, everything has been working fine but now I am getting the following message.

> Unable to complete the operation for the select resource using the specified options. The following error was returned when opening the Exchange Database File: -1213 The Database page size does not match the engine.

I have tried searching for resolutions for this but all of the solutions i can find were either using a different version of exchange or they were using 2 servers (One for Backup Exec and the other being exchange).

My server has not been updated and has been running fine on its current version for the last 2 years!

Help or advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Backup Exec 12.5?  Small Business Server Version?  All updates on Backup Exec